# iCloud App Icon not displayed in Manage Storage

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, app-store, cloudkit

I have created an app (still in TestFlight) that uses cloud kit but it doesn't show the app icon (displays white empty icon) in either

- iOS: Settings.app > iCloud > Storage & Backup > Manage Store
- OSX: System Preferences > iCloud > Manage

I have added (and removed and re added) all icons for iOS, macOS, watchOS to assets.xcassets

Cleared build folder and rebuilt as well as rename the entire project and create a new bundle ID and Cloud Container ID

Used new AppleID's, new simulators, new physical devices (iPhone & Mac) to prevent caching

Increased build numbers to push changes

Added the following to info.plist

```
<key>NSUbiquitousContainers</key> <dict> <key>container-id</key> <dict> <key>NSUbiquitousContainerIsDocumentScopePublic</key> <true/> <key>NSUbiquitousContainerName</key> <string>AppName</string> <key>NSUbiquitousContainerSupportedFolderLevels</key> <string>Any</string> </dict> </dict>
```

I have also reset the CloudKit Development environment

I have seen this asked before (unto 10+ years ago) and also in different forums including apples developer forum but no solid answers.

I'm hoping someone can help solve this issue once and for all so I can upload my app to the App Store.